# JavaScript External files dependency in kendo ui grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I have Two file KendoUIGridFeatures.js & orgs.js which i include in .html page
as show below

`<script src="Scripts/KendoUIGridFeatures.js"></script>`

`<script src="Scripts/Orgs.js"></script>`

I get the following error when loading html page

```
    Uncaught ReferenceError: hideColumn is not defined Orgs.js:201
```

**Why am i getting this Error ?**

If i look into console of google chrome, i see that files were loaded in order and there
were no error except the one mentioned above
//console output

```
 KendoUIGridFetaures Loaded KendoUIGridFeatures.js:3
 Orgs Loaded Orgs.js:3

//KendoUIGridFeatures.js
$(document).ready(function () {

console.log("KendoUIGridFetaures Loaded");
var gridFeaturesLoaded = true;


function hideColumn(e) {

}

function showColumn(e) {
}

function columnResize(e) {
}

function reOrderColumn(e) {
}

function gridDatabound(e) {
}

}



//orgs.js
$(document).ready(function () {

console.log("Orgs Loaded");

$("#" + gridName).kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dsOrg,
    autoBind: false,
    columnHide: hideColumn,
    columnShow: showColumn,
    columnResize: columnResize,
    columnReorder: reOrderColumn,
    dataBound: gridDatabound,

   ..........................
});
});
```

Comment: What is Orgs.js? You are probably missing a resource dependency.

Comment: If you Scroll down, i have shown the content of the orgs.js file at the bottom.

Comment: Ah sorry, missed it, see if my answer below solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are using the function `hideColumn` as a global function, but you have not defined it globally.

When you define a function in `$(document).ready`, that function is only accessible in that scope. So you have to move `hideColumn` (as well as all your other grid functions) out of the `$(document).ready` for it to be accessible.

In **KendoUIGridFeatures.js** you want to move your functions out like this:

```
function hideColumn(e) {}
function showColumn(e) {}
function columnResize(e) {}
function reOrderColumn(e) {}
function gridDatabound(e) {}
//add your other grid functions...

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log("KendoUIGridFetaures Loaded");
    var gridFeaturesLoaded = true;
    //other code you might have...
});
```

Alternatively, you can also put those functions inside the `$(document).ready` of **org.js**, and it will work since you are calling the function inside the same scope.

Comment: Putting them outside of document ready works, but the code in those function is referencing the elements and because of it, it error out.

Also in my code snippet i am using them inside document ready of another file.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you mean, the bottom line is what's in the document ready is only visible in that scope. If you want to leave those functions in "another file", it has to be a global function. Otherwise you have to put those functions in the document ready of where you are calling them.